# HTML-Reloading web page takes me to main page

Tags: html, web

I am creating a website and hosting it myself via IIS. I am trying to traverse pages but it's not really working.

This is my code that will go to my "serivices" page. However, when on this page the URL does not change and when pressing reload I am taking back to the home page.

`<a href="..\html\services.html">Our Services</a>`

So, for example, since my page is www.aasoftwaresolutions.com, when I click "Our Services" it should take me to www.aasoftwaresolutions.com/services.html. It doesn't do this. It will show the webpage but it will still have URL www.aasoftwaresolutions.com and when I press reload on the browser it takes me to the homepage rather than keeping me on services.

Here's my file structure:

F:\Website\ (base directory for website)
F:\Website\html\ (where all the HTML is)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check your spelling of your html file?
I also found out in you question that your spelling is `serivices`. Is that your file name of your html file?

Comment: Yes, the page pops up but then when I press refresh it goes home.. If you go to www.aasoftwaresolutions.com and click Our Services (along the top) you can see what I mean

Comment: you can look inside the browser developer tools and it will tell you the attempted directory for the 404 error. Then make the appropriate measures.

Comment: It's not the 404 error that's the problem, I can traverse to the services.html page BUT when I reload it it goes to the home page. I need to reload it to stay on the services.html page and not go to home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start directory:

it's for example: index.html

```
<a href="..\html\services.html">Our Services</a>
```

the directory is here (for example).

> F:\Website\ (base directory for website) \index.html

with this you are going to:

> F:\Website(base directory for website)\html\services.html

with this `..\` stand back a folder ago.

Comment: I guess, I'm not sure what you mean. I know how file traversals work with .., ., etc. But even If I change the reference to `href="html\services.html` it does the same thing.

Comment: Didn't use this in fix, just changed from redirecting port 80 to port 8080 to just using port 80 and the problem was resolved. But you had the only answer, so here's 15 points I guess